# Cannot find Anaconda install logging

Tags: python, anaconda, logfile, silent

I am having issues installing anaconda silently on some machines.  I am running `Anaconda3-2020_07-Windows-x86_64.exe` `/InstallationType=AllUsers /RegisterPython=1 /AddToPath=1 /S`.  It runs for a bit and creates the Anaconda3 directory in program data but the only files that show up are _conda.exe and uninstall_Anaconda3.exe and the pkgs,Lib,Conda-meta directories, with sub folders and files in them but no python and don't see the rest of the files in the main directory I normally would see on complete install. It also never adds the path environment variables but it registers as installed with windows.  My biggest issue here is there is nothing to go on as to what it is doing.  I have looked everywhere but this thing does not create a logfile.  Am I missing it or is that just an oversight of whoever made this?  If I had a logfile I could troubleshoot this better.

Comment: Currently running into the same issue with 2020.11.

Did you ever get a resolution on this?

Comment: No was convinced it was an issue with that version.  Anaconda does not log anything when installed silently. Most you can get is output through gui but I only  had issues when running silently.  Opened an issue on github and was pointed to this link:  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#i-m-having-trouble-with-the-anaconda-installer-on-windows-how-can-i-debug-my-issue  to use a debugging tool but rolled back to a previous version instead. Going back to a previous version I did not get the issue.

Comment: Currently running into this issue now.  It worked when running it through powershell and software center while a user is logged in, but would fail when it was unassisted.

I tried removing the path to where the install goes and I think it may have just worked as I used a remote tool to do the install that simulates the system.

Will update upon findings tomorrow after lab installation cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying applications I prefer having logfiles, both PADT (PSAppDeployToolkit) and the installer. Found no parameter for the installer, and no files to copy in any TEMP-folder after.

To the problem at hand, installer not running without a user present:
running PsExec (https://aka.ms/Sysinternals) as system account is good enough for the installer to create everything even without a user.

In PADT, put psexec.exe or psexec64.exe in \Files folder with installer:
`Execute-Process -Path "$dirFiles\psexec64.exe" -WorkingDirectory "$dirFiles\" -Parameters "-accepteula -i -s -w $dirFiles\ $dirFiles\Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=AllUsers /S /D=$envProgramData\Anaconda3" -WindowStyle 'Normal'`

A .bat or .cmd file could use:
`psexec64.exe -accepteula -i -s -w %~dp0 Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=AllUsers /S /D=%ANACONDA_INSTALL_FOLDER%`

Uninstall is also best using PsExec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with 2021.05 via SCCM silent install, I had no problem with 2019.03.

Early testing suggests that the SCCM option 'Run installation and uninstall program as 32-bit process on 64-bit clients' helps.

Comment: I consider this an acceptable partial answer; i.e. a contribution to answering process while there is no full answer yet. However, as a new contributor please take the [tour] and maybe you find something helpful for your future posts at [answer].

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I tested this as well on one system that it was previously failing on and it was successful.  I am unsure why though as I am using the 64 bit installer.  CM uses ccm32bitlauncher.exe it looks like to execute it as a 32 bit process but not sure what all it does.  I am installing this through a script though so this is actually launching PowerShell as 32 bit which causes issues when I try to validate the install through the 64 bit uninstall registry key before continuing on to all the configuration steps we require in our environment because it can only see wow6432node uninstall key as 32 bit.

Comment: I will try letting Config Man run it as 64 bit again and in my script execute the 32bit version of cmd and pass the anaconda installer with my arguments to that instead and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've been observing the same problem for 2 years now with different versions. I have also tried different solutions without success.

My solution approach was finally to **repackage Anaconda as an MSI**, with adjustments to our university environment (i.e. folder redirection, SCCM, environment variables) in the Shortcut, Directory, Icon, and Property MSI tables.

In my opinion, the **cause of the problem is to be found in the hardware or hardware drivers**. The problem occurs only with certain PC models: With version 2022.10 consequently with the following PC models: Lenovo ThinkCentre M720s, M920s and Fujitsu ESPRIMO E920. On the following model only occasionally (half yes, half no): Lenovo ThinkCentre M70s And with the following models not at all: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83 and M900

I have a PC lab with M920s and M900 models, where all PCs have the same Windows image and software setup: All M920s have the problem, all M900s do not.